# Kubernetes DNS fails to resolve most of the times but sometimes it works. What can i do to solve this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, dns, flannel

Kubernetes not able to resolve DNS. Container/Pods not able to access Internet.

I have a Kubernetes 2 node cluster on separate AWS EC2 instances (t2.Medium) container networking has been done using:
Flannel version: flannel:v0.10.0-amd64 (image)
Kubernetes version: 1.15.3

DNS Logs
[DNS Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzuxA.png)

[nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVjXx.png)

[Kubernetes svc:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elg2a.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX6UE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOv5I.png)

At times when I delete core-dns pods, the DNS issue gets resolved for some time but it is not consistant. Please suggest what can be done. I flannel mapping may have something to do with this. Please let me know if any other information is also needed.

Comment: on AWS you should be using provided EKS for kubernetes. setting up clusters manually is intended for bare-metal machines (your own data center for example) and is not supported by most cloud providers as it would require to give a lot of control/privileges to users. if you want to play with `kubeadm` then do it on libvirt/KVM virtual machines on your computer where you have full control.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try using kops now.

Answer (score 2):

Errors such you get:  `nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'` indicate that you have problem with the coredns/kube-dns add-on or associated Services.

Please check if you did following steps to debug DNS: [coredns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#check-if-the-dns-pod-is-running).

It also seems that like DNS inside busybox does not work properly.

Try to use busybox images <= **1.28.4**

Change pod configuration file:

```
  containers:
  - name: busybox-image
    image: busybox:1.28.3
```

Learn more about most known dns kubernetes issues: [kubernetes-dns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/#known-issues).

Comment: Does it help ? Would you consider upvote/accept it, it will be useful for community.